# How to change the color of modified files/packages in the Eclipse Package Explorer?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, egit

In Eclipse's Package Explorer I would like to change the color of the font of files and packages that were modified (managed by the Git plugin, these files are preceded by `>`).

I went to *Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts*, but I was not able to find which option (if any) controls this case.

Alternatively, is there any dark theme for Eclipse that does not show dark text over dark background?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change the foreground color, background color, and font for *Uncommitted* files. Go to *General* > _Appearance > *Colors and Fonts* and open the *Git* category. At its end, you'll find the *Uncommitted* entries.

In this example screenshot, the foreground color is changed to red:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! I have been looking for it for a long time and it kept eluding me :) Thank you!

Comment: Any way to update selected file bg-color as in dark theme in Eclipse 2020-06 uses windows highlight colors which are not visible on dark background of eclipse and its also issue on many dialogs.